# Sites freeze after win 10 install and no flash

Tags: google-chrome, flash, firefox, windows-10, freeze

I am have a peculiar issue where sites like facebook, gmail, netflix, hulu are hanging up. There are two issues I think that might be related though I can't be sure. 
1) The first is that videos on youtube, hulu, netflix, etc., all hang at some instances. They will start playing after multiple refreshes, but then might revert back to either playing with no sound, or not playing at all once paused for a few minutes. At first I thought this was due to a videocard driver issue so I upgraded my driver. I have NVIDIA GeForce 610M with driver version 10.18.13.6191. This did not fix it.

2) Shortly after, chrome and firefox experienced issues of freezing on certain websites, (facebook, gmail, youtube, twitter) at which point the flash player kept crashing. After a day of rummaging around, I uninstalled flash from my computer and also disabled it on Chrome. Although the crash errors no longer appear, the sites listed above still hang -- mostly in Chrome. And forget about hulu and netflix. I am at the end of my wits. Any solution?

All this happened after I installed windows 10 recently.

Answer (score 0):

I had such a problem with google-chrome and that solution was disabling `Use hardware acceleration when available` in the settings.

Comment: I just tried that. Unfortunately, it didn't help. :(